# Compare two Excel sheet and find out mismatches using a Java program

Tags: java, excel, pdf, comparison, forms

I have two similar Excel sheets, i.e. column name and rows contents are the same. I have to write a Java program to compare those two Excel sheets and generate simple HTML form for showing the mismatches in it. Example in Excel sheet position (1 row, 3 column) contain value 15 and other excel has of 20. So I have to generate the HTML form (UI ) or Simple report with which column has mismatches and what value in it

Please help me on this.Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Why does the program have to be simple?

Comment: When you say excel sheet do you mean xls or xlsx or csv or ... ?

Comment: @bzlm Sorry Since I am new to java so i used that word simple . I need a java program for the scenario which i have mentioned above.

Comment: I thought you needed to *write* one. ;)

Comment: @peter.petrov xls or xslx .Is there any difference in the way handling .xls and .xlsx in java?

Comment: I don't know but I guess if you add more details about the file format the chance for getting a proper answer would increase.

Comment: I would consider exporting the excel spreadsheet to CSV and reading it using the [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) library.